# Draw custom drawable shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to draw a custom shape in `xml` layout like below :

[image]

I tried to do some code in `XML` but i do not understand how to give shadow effect to outline of this shadow.

What i did :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>

                <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        android:bottom="6dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@color/color_white"
                android:startColor="@color/color_white"
                android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:radius="6dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What i got in result :

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how can i give shadow to outline as in the mentioned above picture? OR any other solution like 9 patch image. How can i draw such 9 patch image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better way Don't create whole shape using **`layer-list`**

- The main disadvantage using that is you need to give fixed `hight` and `width` of `shape`

Use Simple way just create top arrow using **`layer-list`** and than use as below sample

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

> @drawable/test"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/white" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is not showing shadow in the outline ?

Comment: Can you tell me how can i attach it to my layout ? Means when i put this as background of my linear layout . Linear layout does not show it as

Comment: Okay Thank you . i check it

Comment: Yes this solves my problem , your solution also solved the problem of content height and width as i don't have to pass static height and width in drawable  layout. Thanks a ton man :)

Answer (score 1):

You create layered shaped as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        >
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        >
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        >
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="70%"
            android:pivotY="40%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#05CCCCCC" android:endColor="#05CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="70%"
            android:pivotY="40%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#20CCCCCC" android:endColor="#20CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="60%"
            android:pivotY="45%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#30CCCCCC" android:endColor="#30CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>

                <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="1dp"
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:startColor="@android:color/white"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Hello @Pavneet Thanks for answer . The solution you have given draws the shape fine but i have to give fixed height and width , But please the accepted answer . it also  gives solution for height and width. Thanks

Comment: I gave an answer as per your code, it wasn't mentioned as a requirement and requirements are missing in accepted answer though it's your choice to accept the best fit, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this:**

> **if you remove corner then delete <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_5"/>  this line.**


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:width="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:height="@dimen/font_20"
            android:gravity="top|left">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="60%"
                android:pivotY="80%"
                android:toDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>

                    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                </shape>

            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="36dp"
            android:bottom="6dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_5"/>

                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Hello @Riya Thanks for answer . The solution you have given draws the shape fine but i have to give fixed height and width , But please the accepted answer . it also  gives solution for height and width. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:width="121dp"
    android:height="37dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke
            android:color="@color/lightgrey"
            android:width="1dp"/>

    </shape>

</item>
<item
    android:width="21dp"
    android:height="21dp"
    android:gravity="top|left">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/lightgrey"
                android:width="1dp"/>

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

            <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:gravity="top|left">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"/>

            <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="36dp"
    android:bottom="6dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:type="linear" />

    </shape>

</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hello @Diwakar Thanks for answer . The solution you have given draws the shape fine but i have to give fixed height and width , But please the accepted answer . it also  gives solution for height and width. Thanks